# Trying to find missing records in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

So I have a table called `stage_accounts` which is showing there are 319561 records in the table and `fact_accounts` is showing there are 319550 records in the table. In order for a record to be unique these tables use a composite primary key made up of `date_code` and `account_id`.

Why can't I get what 11 records are missing from `fact_accounts` using the query below, is here any other way I can retrieve those missing records

I tried:

```
SELECT stage.*
FROM stage_accounts stage
LEFT JOIN fact_accounts fact
    ON stage.date_code = fact.date_code AND stage.client_account_id = fact.client_account_id
WHERE fact.date_code IS NULL OR fact.client_account_id IS NULL;
```

Also tried:

```
SELECT stage.*
FROM stage_accounts stage
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM fact_accounts fact
    WHERE stage.date_code = fact.date_code AND stage.account_id = fact.account_id
);
```

Comment: Assuming what you tried returned no results then presumably there are duplicates for a `date_code, client_account_id` in `stage_accounts`. So that combo does exist in `fact_accounts` but not the same number of them

Comment: @MartinSmith How can I check if there are duplicates in stage_accounts?

Comment: `SELECT stage.client_account_id, stage.date_code FROM stage_accounts stage GROUP BY stage.client_account_id, stage.date_code HAVING COUNT(*) >1`

Comment: since your table does not look very big. try to use `EXCEPT`, do table A EXCEPT B, and B EXCEPT A, that will give what is the extra based on the combination. bigger count does not always mean it has values that do not exist from the table having less number of record

Comment: How many rows do you return when you with the first left join query? That should do it however there may be duplicates. An enhanced solution from there may be to add a group by and then a having clause that allows you to return counts of records that are duplicated.

Comment: @MartinSmith there are duplicates. that query helped to find the duplicates. thank you

Comment: So this wasn't correct : `these tables use a composite primary key made up of date_code and account_id`